# How to make a "key generator" knowing the formula

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have the formula to check 9 integers,

First digit(d1) must be:  1, 2, 5, 6, 8 or 9
Last digit(d9) must be: 0 or 9
9xd1+8xd2+7xd3+6xd4+5xd5+4xd6+3xd7+2xd8+d9 mod 11 = 0

I can "validate" the key, but how can I generate more of this, knowing the conditions for it to be right?

How can I generate 9 different integers from 0 to 9 and check them under this formula?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: If it is only 9 numbers, why not just brute force it?

Comment: The simple answer would be to generate random keys and then check them against that formula...

Comment: A simple way would be to generate each segment as a string the concatenate them into the final number. No guessing then, the number generated will follow all the rules. Once it is concatenated, just cast it back to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate the first 7 digits randomly, calculating the formula for those digits.
2. Set the 9th digit's value to 9, and add it to the formula.
3. Calculate a value for the 8th digit based on the mod of the result of the formula that causes the result of the formula to be mod 11 = 0.
4. For the exception case where attempting to do this causes mod 11 = 9, set the 9th digit to 0.

Implementation:

```
Private randGen As New Random()

Function GenNum() As Integer
   Dim digits(0 To 8) As Integer
   GenNum = 0
   Dim checkSum As Integer
   digits(0) = randGen.Next(6) + 1
   If digits(0) >= 3 Then digits(0) += 2
   If digits(0) >= 7 Then digits(0) += 1
   checkSum += digits(0) * 9
   For d As Integer = 1 To 6
      digits(d) = randGen.Next(10)
      checkSum += digits(d) * (9 - d)
   Next
   digits(8) = 9
   checkSum += digits(8)
   If (checkSum Mod 11) Mod 2 = 1 Then
      digits(7) = (11 - (checkSum Mod 11)) \ 2
   Else
      digits(7) = ((12 - (checkSum Mod 11)) \ 2 + 4) Mod 10
   End If
   checkSum += digits(7) * 2
   If checkSum Mod 11 = 9 Then digits(8) = 0
   Dim pow10 As Integer = 1
   For d As Integer = 8 To 0 Step -1
      GenNum += pow10 * digits(d)
      pow10 *= 10
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: BlueMonk, your code is only missing one thing, that I am trying to do but just can't...

It has to end with a 0 or a 9.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you to generate integers from 0 to 9.

here is how your form should look like:
[image]

and here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim NumRandom As Random = New Random
Dim X, Y, Z As Integer

Private Sub GenerateBUT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GenerateBUT.Click
    Dim a(9), i, j, RN As Integer
    Dim flag As Boolean
    flag = False
    i = 1
    a(j) = 1
    Do While i <= 9
        Randomize()
        RN = CInt(Int(9 * Rnd()) + 1)
        For j = 1 To i
            If (a(j)) = RN Then
                flag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If flag = True Then
            flag = False
        Else
            a(i) = RN
            i = i + 1S
        End If
    Loop
    Label1.Text = a(1)
    Label2.Text = a(2)
    Label3.Text = a(3)
    Label4.Text = a(4)
    Label5.Text = a(5)
    Label6.Text = a(6)
    Label7.Text = a(7)
    Label8.Text = a(8)
    Label9.Text = a(9)
    Z = Label4.Text
    Y = Label5.Text
    X = Z + Y
    X = X - Label3.Text
    If X > 1 And X < 10 Then
        X = NumRandom.Next(1, 7)
        If X = 1 Then
            Label1.Text = "0"
        ElseIf X = 2 Then
            Label2.Text = "0"
        ElseIf X = 3 Then
            Label3.Text = "0"
        ElseIf X = 4 Then
            Label4.Text = "0"
        ElseIf X = 5 Then
            Label5.Text = "0"
        ElseIf X = 6 Then
            Label6.Text = "0"
        ElseIf X = 7 Then
            Label7.Text = "0"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class